# XLSX Sheetnames unexpectedly being truncated by using Openpyxl load_workbook

Tags: csv, openpyxl, xlsx

I wrote a simple script to read a thousand xlsx files, with files having 400~500 Sheets and names with more than 50 characters. After obtaining the sheet names, the script would save those names into csv files that would eventually upload to a DB.  Here is the script:

```
extension = 'XLSX'
xlsxfiles = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
for xlsxfile in xlsxfiles:
    fins = op.load_workbook(xlsxfile,read_only=True)
    sheetnames = fins.sheetnames
    with open('test_xlsx-'+xlsxfile+'.csv','w',newline = '') as fout:
    fout.write(str(xlsxfile))
```

I have two issues that need help:

1. Openpyxl load_workbook only returned 31 characters of the sheetnames. If more than 31, it  truncates to “Sheetname something something_4””, but it should be
   “Sheetname something something Real”
   I tried Pandas.ExcelFile.sheet_names but got the same issue.
2. The CSV file saved the sheetnames as a column by column.

   [‘Cover Page’       ‘Sheetname something something_4’       ‘Sheetname other’]

But I need the data as a row by row and drop all “[“ or “ ’ “.

```
  Cover Page

  Sheetame something something Real

  Sheetname other
```

I am a novice in Python. All ideas and comments are welcome.

Comment: The Excel limitation is 31 characters: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53e88252-9d4a-4c3e-8182-956d3fccebcb/maximum-excel-sheet-name-length?forum=sqlintegrationservices I'm not sure how those sheets have longer names, but it's not supported by Excel's UI.

Comment: Yes, that's right, More than 31  characters in a sheet name is not supported by Excel UI. However the Excle file itself is allowed to do so. I think it can be up to 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Still unable to get how to fix the first 31-characters issue.

For the second issue, I add a for loop for going through each sheet name and treat each one as a list.  Here is code.

```
extension = 'XLSX'
xlsxfiles = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
for xlsxfile in xlsxfiles:
    fins = op.load_workbook(xlsxfile,read_only=True)
    sheetnames = fins.sheetnames
    with open('test_xlsx-'+xlsxfile+'.csv','w',newline = '') as fout:
        sheetnameout = csv.writer(fout)
        for name in sheetnames:
            sheetnameout.writerow([name])     # That "[]" took me 8 hours.  
    fout.close()
```

Again, I am novice in Python. All ideas and comments are welcome.